# Windows service on system startup behaves differently

Tags: sql-server, windows-services

I have a Windows service which inserts into a database whenever there is a change in data from an OPC Server(KepServer). The service inserts correctly when I manually start it from the Services Task Manager of Windows 7. But the service only inserts one row of data when starting up on system startup, whereas the desired number of rows must be 20. Because it is Windows Service, it is difficult to debug and it is not giving any error as well.

jjag

OS:Windows 7;
DB:SQL Server Express;
Win Service:run under Administrator

My code:

```
Protected Overrides Sub OnStart(ByVal args() As String)
    ' Add code here to start your service. 
    'Create a new OPC Server object

    ConnectedOPCServer = New OPCServer
    ConnectedOPCServer.Connect("KEPware.KEPServerEx.V5")
    Try
        ' Add the group and set its update rate
        ConnectedServerGroups = ConnectedOPCServer.OPCGroups
        ConnectedGroup = ConnectedServerGroups.Add("Test1")
    Catch ex As Exception
        ' Error handling
    End Try

    ' Set the update rate for the group
    ConnectedGroup.UpdateRate = 400

    ' Subscribe the group so that you will be able to get the data change
    ' callbacks from the server
    ConnectedGroup.IsSubscribed = True

    ItemCount = 3
    OPCItemIDs(1) = "Channel2.Device1.EndDate"
    OPCItemIDs(2) = "Channel2.Device1.Material"
    OPCItemIDs(3) = "Channel2.Device1.BatchSchedule"
    ClientHandles(1) = 1
    ClientHandles(2) = 2
    ClientHandles(3) = 3
    Try
        ' Establish a connection to the OPC item interface of the connected group
        OPCItemCollection = ConnectedGroup.OPCItems
        OPCItemCollection.DefaultIsActive = True
        OPCItemCollection.AddItems(ItemCount, OPCItemIDs, ClientHandles, ItemServerHandles, ItemServerErrors)
    Catch ex As Exception
        ' Error handling
    End Try
    EventLog1.WriteEntry("In OnStart")
End Sub

Public Sub ConnectedGroup_DataChange(ByVal TransactionID As Integer, ByVal NumItems As Integer, ByRef ClientHandles As System.Array, ByRef ItemValues As System.Array, ByRef Qualities As System.Array, ByRef TimeStamps As System.Array) Handles ConnectedGroup.DataChange

    'This is my sub which inserts into database in the event of data change from OPC Server
    Const NoOfItems = 3

    Dim ObjOPCItem As OPCAutomation.OPCItem
    Dim Array_Values(NoOfItems) As Object


    For Each ObjOPCItem In OPCItemCollection
        Array_Values(ObjOPCItem.ClientHandle) = ObjOPCItem.Value
    Next
    ObjOPCItem = Nothing

    Dim sql As String

    sql = "INSERT INTO BatchReport (BatchCode,BatchNumber)VALUES(@AV,@AVa);"

    If Array_Values(3) < 20 Then
        Try
            connection.Open()
            dataadapter.InsertCommand = New SqlCommand(sql, connection)
            dataadapter.InsertCommand.Parameters.Add("@AV", SqlDbType.Int, 4).Value = Array_Values(1)
            dataadapter.InsertCommand.Parameters.Add("@AVa", SqlDbType.Int, 4).Value = Array_Values(3)
            dataadapter.InsertCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()
        Catch ex As Exception
            MsgBox(ex.ToString)
        End Try
        connection.Close()
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: no code shown, how do you expect accurate answers? Hint: it's probably permissions...

Comment: When you "manually start it" do you get the "Permission to logon as a service has been granted" message?  Thats temporary and wouldn't be in effect upon reboot afaik. Apply this permission permanently via a policy.

Comment: @MitchWheat-Sorry, just edited question with code addition. Thanks anyway for the quick response.

Comment: @NathanSkerl - The service cannot connect to DB when logging in as Local System, but it can connect when logged in as Administrator user. I tried changing the policy via Local Policies to the specific user. But still the service only writes one row of data. Can it still write anything if it has permission issues? I am really stuck on it. I am new to SQL Server programming as well.

Comment: No, I cant think of a reason why permissions were limit you to insert only single row. Look again at your code, your loop "foreach... next" does not include the insert statement. Appears you just loop through your collection then insert once, resulting in one row.

Comment: There were two things that caused the inconsistent behaviour of my Windows Service. First was, I used "User Instance= True;" in my connection string which wasn't needed and the second was, the timing of the dependent service on computer start-up. I spent lots of hours trying to fix this because of the difficulty in debugging a Service and since I'm new to programming as well. In hindsight, the problem was the connection string and I still don't understand why User Instance makes such a difference.